# Firefox doesn't display flash if inside transform-style:preserve-3d

Tags: flash, firefox, css, transform

I am embedding a flash player inside a coverflow-style display.

I use css3 `transform-style:preserve-3d;` on one of the flash's ancestors in order to z-index the elements which are holding my flash embeds according to their 3d orientation (and not their order in the DOM).

Firefox hides the flash embed if one of it's ancestors has the preserve-3d css property. It will render the flash if I remove this property.

Other browsers will render this properly.

Here is a test case fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ek59Y/1/

Is this expected behavior? is this a bug?

my browsers:

- firefox 17.0 (tested on 15.0 also)
- chrome 23.0

**EDIT:**

Setting the transform-style to flat yields the same result  as removing the property altogether (renders properly).

Comment: Browsers other than firefox will ignore `-moz-transform-style`. Guess why? :-)

Comment: Sorry, this was a test case. updated now.

Comment: other browsers = chrome?

Comment: In this case, I am currently concerned only with these two browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, this is a Firefox bug.

I have opened up a ticket in bugzilla and a Mozilla representative stated that Firefox does not support displaying flash videos with `wmode=window` and `preserve-3d`.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=819763